# How to convert `if` / `else` into 1 line of code?

Tags: python

I have a python logic like this:

```
file = 'POMNI2022.csv'

pomni=False

if 'POMNI' in file:
    pomni=True
else:
    pass
```

Is there any way I can use just 1 line code for the if else logic here?

Comment: You can get rid of two lines really quickly by just getting rid of the do-nothing `else` clause.

Comment: What wrong with just `pomni = 'POMNI' in file`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`:

```
pomni = 'POMNI' in file
```

Comment: There would also be this I believe in the case of an actual else clause?  
result = 3 if <condition> else 4

Comment: Assuming that each clause consists of a single expression statement, yes.